# How to set a specific min and max to random number

Tags: java, random, numbers

I wanted to print a random number that starts with 30 and ends with 95. But it still prints 29 and lower. Here's my the code of formula that I used.

```
ran_num = (95 - 30 + 1) + 30;
```

Comment: Do you want to get a random number between 30 and 95 (each inclusively)?

Comment: yes. that's what I want to do.

Comment: Then use a `Random` or a `ThreadLocalRandom`, no need for custom calculations...

Comment: The code in the question does not generate any random numbers, since it's all fixed values. `ran_num` will always be assigned value `96`!!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a random number between 30 and 95 by using a `ThreadLocalRandom` for example.

A code that prints 10 random numbers in that range could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(30, 96)); // upper border exclusive
}
```

If you want to store a random in a variable, write something like

```
int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(30, 96);
```

Comment: can I put that in a variable?

Comment: @moonman sure, you can store the result of that call in an `int`...

Comment: thank you sir. this really help